# Prove $\Lambda (n)=-\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \log(d)$

Tags: number-theory

Prove $\Lambda (n)=-\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \log(d)$

I'm not sure where to begin with this. $\Lambda (n)$ is the Von Mangodt function that is defined by $\Lambda (n) = \log p$ if n is a power of the prime p and $0$ otherwise.

Progress:
Start by showing $\sum_{d | n}\Lambda = \log(n)$
For $n=1$ it holds since $\Lambda(1)=0=\log 1$. For $n$ greater or equal to $2$, we have $\sum_{d | n}\Lambda = \sum_{p^m | n}\log p = \log(n)$

Comment: Start by showing $\log n=\sum_{d\mid n} \Lambda(d)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i've added that in, but i'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: After what Thomas Andrews said, use the [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), and that $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1_{n = 1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First show that, for all $n$:

$$\log n = \sum_{d\mid n} \Lambda(d)$$

So, by Möbius inversion:

$$\begin{align}\Lambda (n) &=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\log\left(\frac n d\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\left(\log n -\log d\right)\\
&=\log n\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)-\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\log d\\
&=-\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\log d
\end{align}$$

The last step because, when $n>1$, $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=0$, and when $n=1$, $\log n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the long proof, but also the most interesting. For $\Re s>1$
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1}p^{-sk}) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}.$$

So that 
$$\ln \zeta(s) = -\sum_p \ln(1-p^{-s}) = \sum_{p}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$$
and
$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \frac{d}{ds} \ln \zeta(s) =-\sum_{p}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}\ln p^k = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s}.$$
On the other hand
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_p(1-p^{-s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}, \qquad \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2} = \frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}\ln(n)$$
and hence
$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2} \zeta(s) = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}\ln(n))(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \ln(d)$$
i.e.
$$\Lambda(n) = -\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \ln(d).$$

Comment: This proof also elucidates why the van-Mandoldt function comes up in the first place. +1